# What do you call the non-narrative aspects of a novel?

Tags: word-request

There are different aspects in a novel and one of the major aspects is the narrative aspect of a novel. What do you call the other aspects? I am thinking non-narrative, but non-narrative aspects of a novel is vague and non-descript. I, honestly, don't know what all of the aspects are, but I think there's only one another aspect aside the narrative aspect of a novel and that it encompasses worldbuilding, so that's why I wouldn't choose "non-narrative" as an adjective.

What would be a better word than "non-narrative"?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, there are two words used to refer to the two main writing aspects of a novel. The *narrative* describes what's happening, and the [**dialogue**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialogue) represents what the characters are saying:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **3** : the conversational element of literary or dramatic composition
>   // very little *dialogue* in this film
>   // writes realistic *dialogue*

---

Everything in a novel, as a story, *can* be described as narrative, but normally a clear distinction is made between narrative and dialogue. In visual media, such as movies, TV shows, and plays, dialogue is commonly contrasted with *action* rather than narrative.